# How to supress default print in awk?

Tags: awk, gawk

This is with gawk 4.0.0, running on Windows 7 with cygwin. The program is invoked like

```
gawk -f procjournal.gawk testdata
```

I have some data that looks like this:

```
"Date";"Type";"Amount";"Balance"
"6/11/2013 11:51:17 AM";"Transaction Tax";-427.5;399313884.46
"6/11/2013 11:51:17 AM";"Market Transaction";47500;399314311.96
"6/11/2013 11:12:42 AM";"Transaction Tax";-549.92;399266811.96
"6/11/2013 11:12:42 AM";"Market Transaction";61101.78;399267361.88
```

I want to extract the lines for transactions, strip the date part from the 1st field, and reformat the time stamp as a decimal. I thought I could do it with this awk program:

```
FS=";"
OFS=";"
/Market Transaction/ {
    split($1, itemdate, " ");
    tmp = itemdate[2];
    split(tmp, hms, ":");
    timestamp = hms[3] + (hms[2] * 60) + (hms[1] * 3600);
    if (itemdate[3] == "AM")
       timestamp += 12 * 3600;
    timestamp /= 3600.0;
    $1 = timestamp;
    print;
}
```

but my output looks like this:

```
"Date";"Type";"Amount";"Balance"
"Date";"Type";"Amount";"Balance"
"6/11/2013 11:51:17 AM";"Transaction Tax";-427.5;399313884.46
"6/11/2013 11:51:17 AM";"Transaction Tax";-427.5;399313884.46
"6/11/2013 11:51:17 AM";"Market Transaction";47500;399314311.96
"6/11/2013 11:51:17 AM";"Market Transaction";47500;399314311.96
11.8547;"Market Transaction";47500;399314311.96
"6/11/2013 11:12:42 AM";"Transaction Tax";-549.92;399266811.96
"6/11/2013 11:12:42 AM";"Transaction Tax";-549.92;399266811.96
"6/11/2013 11:12:42 AM";"Market Transaction";61101.78;399267361.88
"6/11/2013 11:12:42 AM";"Market Transaction";61101.78;399267361.88
11.2117;"Market Transaction";61101.78;399267361.88
```

Why are non-matching lines being printed, and how do I suppress that?

Comment: You have FS=";" outside of an action block and therefore it's a condition. As such it evaluates to true and invokes the default action of printing the current record. Ditto for OFS=";". See @Jaypal's answer for how to fix that, and it's also a good idea to use `FS=OFS=";"` for conciseness when you want both to have the same value.

Answer (score 6):

Change the script to include the separators in `BEGIN` block.

**Script Content:**

```
BEGIN {
FS=";"
OFS=";"
}
/Market Transaction/ {
    split($1, itemdate, " ");
    tmp = itemdate[2];
    split(tmp, hms, ":");
    timestamp = hms[3] + (hms[2] * 60) + (hms[1] * 3600);
    if (itemdate[3] == "AM")
       timestamp += 12 * 3600;
    timestamp /= 3600.0;
    $1 = timestamp;
    print;
}
```

Comment: Don't think this is it. The program is stored in a file, invoked with `gawk -f`. When I tried your suggestion I got `backslash not last character on line`.

Comment: The big problem is that the OP changes the input and output field separators for each line, and does very strange and bad things. Put them inside the `BEGIN` block and magically all will work, or I hope so. Those backslashes have non sense for me. It gives same error in Linux.

Comment: Aaah, Now that you updated the question it makes sense. You just need to include the `FS` and `OFS` in `BEGIN` block. Do that and you should get two lines of output.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but a different way to calculate the time:

```
if (match($1, /([0-9]?[0-9]):([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]) ([AP]M)/, a)) {
    $1 = a[1] + (a[2]*60 + a[3])/3600 + (a[4] == "PM" ? 12 : 0)
}
```